# What is the meaning for "bounded above"?

Tags: meaning, terminology

> For the analysis to correspond usefully to the actual execution time, the time required to perform a step must be guaranteed to be bounded above by a constant
>   <sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms))</sub>

By looking meaning for bound I got as "sudden long step". With this meaning I cannot understand the above statement meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bound has another meaning, "a limiting value", per Oxford. That's how it's being used. Bounded *above* means that it's limited on the upper end of its range, as though it has a wall *above* its possibilities. So the sentence means that the time cannot be greater than a certain fixed limit.

Comment: Confused with google dictionary. No where it is mentioned like limit

Comment: @vinothcse2000: It does show up eventually if you look in [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=define+bound&form=OSDSRC) and expand the given definition.

Comment: it was mentioned like leap stride.. Where we were getting the meaning like limit. Can you quote which one I have to expand

Comment: @vinothcse2000: The definition should be right there above the search results; if you expand it and check "bound²", it's the third entry under "noun".